# loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler: not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, vpn

I'm trying to use the VPN iOS 8, for this I created a **new project> iOS> Single Application**. Them to active VPN Connections I go to **capabilities** and turn on **Personal VPN**.

With these simple steps Xcode already generated for me:

[image]

Now, to test if the VPN is active or not, I used the code below in my viewDidLoad method:

```
#import <NetworkExtension/NetworkExtension.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];

    [manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            NSLog(@"Load error: %@", error);
        } else {
            // No errors! The rest of your codes goes here...
            NSLog(@"VPN seems to be fine.");
        }
    }];

}
```

The problem with this code is that it seems that I am not getting any messages on the console, the problem is that the method **"loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler"** not being called, why this is happening?

Comment: I think you should implement this code under `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of **AppDelegate** file instead of in this `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I don't know why, but it seems that the loadFromPreferences will call the completion handler only after The AppDelegate passed the 'applicationDidBecomeActive' method. If you are performing work before that point of the App's life cycle, waiting for the completion handler will result in infinite waiting...

So just wait for "AppDelegate.applicationDidBecomeActive" to perform "loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler"